# VTK: setting transparent renderer background

Tags: transparency, opacity, vtk, renderer

I am allowed to define the backgroundColor of a renderer by calling

```
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.SetBackground(0,255,0)
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My question:

Is it possible to set the opacity of the background ?

You can see my problem (with multiple viewports) in my example image. I could get rid of this "cutting" by simply using transparent backgrounds...

thanks in advance!

Comment: You should post that as solution and accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a solution :

you can set a layer for each renderer. Default is Layer 0 (not transparent). Everything greater than layer 0 will be transparent. But keep in mind to set at least a empty renderer (no volume or object) with a background-color on layer 0 to avoid ugly reflections.

```
renderer.SetBackground(255,255,255)
renderer.SetLayer(0)

# transparency layer
renderer.SetLayer(1)
renderer.addVolume(....)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For those who want to use transparency in a screenshot.

```py
render_window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
render_window.AddRenderer(renderer)
render_window.SetAlphaBitPlanes(1)  # Enable usage of alpha channel
...
w2if = vtk.vtkWindowToImageFilter()
w2if.SetInput(render_win)
w2if.SetInputBufferTypeToRGBA()  # Also record the alpha (transparency) channel
...
```

More details in this [official vtk example](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/Screenshot).

---

Edit: In addition, if the above is not working (e.g. the background is transparent but the actors are white/not rendered properly), you can try to enable depth peeling.

Before the above code snippet you should add

```py
# the renderer, as in the question
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.AddActor(actor)
renderer.SetBackground(0,255,0)
renderer.SetBackgroundAlpha(0.2)  # add background opacity value
renderer.SetUseDepthPeeling(1)  # only works with current GPUs
renderer.SetOcclusionRatio(0.2)  # 0. is better, but much slower
```

You might also need to increase the maximum number of peels (default is 4). Check [this VTK Wiki page for more details](https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Depth_Peeling).

Comment: Neither this not the official vtk example work for me.

Comment: For some reason this makes my `vtkPNGWriter` object write everything almost transparently. Quite odd. Changing back to `w2if.SetInputBufferTypeToRGB()` corrects the transparency of the polygonal data, but makes the background opaque again.

Answer (score 0):

for set background on vtkFullScreenRenderWindow function,
you can use the [File](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-4/walden/color.pdf) to find your ideal color.